# Find the general solution of differential equation $y''+2y'+y=e^{-t} \ln t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of differential equation $y''+2y'+y=\mathrm{e}^{-t}\ln t$.

For $y_c$, the A.E. is $m^2+2m+1=0\;\Rightarrow (m+1)^2=0\Rightarrow m=-1,-1 $.

Therefore, $y_c=(c_1+c_2t)e^{-t}$

But how to find $y_p$?

Comment: Put at first $y=ze^{-t}$ to to take off the exponential.

Comment: You need here two parameters .

Comment: As noted, $e^{-t}\ln t$ is not of the proper form to use undetermined coefficients.  So you could try variation of parameters to find a $y_p$.  Your DE textbook should have an explanation of that.

Answer (score 1):

With the change $y=ze^{-t}$, we have

$y'=(z'-z)e^{-t}$
and

$y''=(z''-2z'+z)e^{-t}$

so, the equation becomes

$$z''=\ln t$$ which gives by parts integration

$$z'=t\ln t-t+C$$

and

$$z=\frac{t^2}{2}\ln t-\frac{t^2}{4}-\frac{t^2}{2}+Ct+K.$$

or

$$z=\frac{t^2}{2}(\ln t-\frac{3}{2})+Ct+K.$$

thus

$$\color{green}{y=[\frac{t^2}{2}(\ln t-\frac{3}{2})+Ct+K]e^{-t}}.$$

where $C,K$ are constant.